# C# FTP ListDirectory does not return results

Tags: c#

I have the following function which is supposed to get a list of files in a remote FTP directory. However, the code does not error, but it also does not return anything. I've tracked that the code gets as far as the `response = reqFTP.GetReponse()` but no further - there is no error generated, but logging messages after this line do not get triggered, but up to this line do.

Can anyone help?

```
private string[] GetFileList()
{
    string[] downloadFiles;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    WebResponse response = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://www.myserver.com/"));
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
        response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
        reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            result.Append(line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
        return result.ToString().Split('\n');
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        downloadFiles = null;
        return downloadFiles;
    }
}
```

Note: I've confirmed that the directory in question has files, and that the username/password are correct.

Comment: Did you confirm that passive mode works for the server?

Comment: If I change passive to false, I get an error: The data connection was made from an address that is different than the address to which the FTP connection was made.